# on activityresult undefined for the type object

Tags: android

```
package ianco.test.andrei;

            import java.io.File;

            import android.app.Activity;
            import android.content.Intent; 

            import android.net.Uri;
            import android.os.Bundle;
             import android.os.Environment;
            import android.util.Log;
            import android.view.View;
              import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
              import android.widget.Button;
              import android.widget.EditText;
          public class BrowsePicture extends Activity {

//YOU CAN EDIT THIS TO WHATEVER YOU WANT
private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;

private String filePath;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

   Button sButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
   sButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
              File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/sdcard/yourfolder");
                Log.d("File path ", dir.getPath());
                String dirPath=dir.getAbsolutePath();
                if(dir.exists() && dir.isDirectory()) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    // tells your intent to get the contents
                    // opens the URI for your image directory on your sdcard
                                    //its upto you what data you want image or video.
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                //  intent.setType("video/*");
                    intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(dir));
                //  intent.setType("media/*");
                //  intent.
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    showToast("No file exist to show");
                }   
}

//UPDATED
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

     if (requestCode == 1) {
         if (data==null) {
            showToast("No image selected");
            //finish();
        }
         else
         {
         Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

      //  String filemanagerstring = selectedImageUri.getPath();

         //MEDIA GALLERY
       String  selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);

         if(selectedImagePath!=null)
         {
             Intent intent = new Intent();
             intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
             intent.setData(selectedImageUri);
             startActivity(intent);
         }

         else
         {
             showToast("Image path not correct");
         }


     }
        }
```

}

in my code from below i have some errors:

1.`super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);`
 i get The method onActivityResult(int, int, Intent) is undefined for the type Object
2.The method getPath(Uri) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to be more careful with your curly braces. You've defined the onActivityResult() inside of your setOnClickListener() method.